# How to get languages list in Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

Hello
i need to get the list of the languages defined on an Android device and would like to populate a Spinner with language code and language name. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance and greetings
c.

Comment: What do you mean by 'defined on an Android device?' Do you just mean the possible Locales? (such as en-rUS, fr-rFR, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
```

Comment: You should add the essential parts of the linked article to prevent that your answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<String> getLanguages() {
    String[] locales = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        if (locale.getLanguage().length() == 2) {
            if (!isLanguageInList(list, locale)) {
                list.add(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}

private static boolean isLanguageInList(List<String> list, Locale locale) {
    if (list == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String item: list) {
        if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(locale.getDisplayLanguage())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Locale.getAvailableLocales()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue. I've figured out how get locales defined in

`phone settings -> system -> languages and input`

kotlin

```kotlin
val locales = Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales
```

this works since API 24.